# Installing an updated byobu on Debian

Tags: debian, installation, byobu

The [Debian package for byobu](https://packages.qa.debian.org/b/byobu.html) still points to version 5.112-1 from 2016-09-16 while there were several [new versions](https://launchpad.net/byobu/+download) released since then.

Is there any chance that the Debian package will get updated any time soon? And what would be the best way to get a more recent version installed in the meantime (if possible at all)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed!  I happen to be the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.org), and I've recently been approved as a Debian Maintainer, which enables me to upload to Debian now.

Comment: That's great news! Any comments on the 2nd part of the question, on what to do in the meantime? :)